# Netbeans breaks on anonymous inner class defined outside its class: invalid syntax?

Tags: java, netbeans

EDIT

Yet another update. Since it worked fine on the command line via javac but not in netbeans, I tried what was suggested by a_horse_with_no_name. Turning off "compile on save" in Netbeans also fixes the problem and makes the program work again. So the anonymous inner class issue was only an issue within Netbeans and only if "compile on save" was turned on.

So the problem was a Netbeans bug related to compile on save.

Also, since some people seemed to have such a major issue with code that would not compile if copy/pasted, I simplified the example even more. Removal made the sample no longer represent the basic idea of what my use case was doing, but it was not necessary for the question at hand.

...and now another interesting little update. Apparently the Netbeans error reporting is still weirding out sometimes even with compile on save turned off, but when it does, it at least is not effecting execution when I tell it to run. So the error reporting analysis must be tied to the same back end tool that the compile on save feature is tied to. So the bug is likely with specifically whatever back end tool that is.

END EDIT

After making an anonymous inner class in another class' code, Netbeans is freaking out about it. As long as it is there, Netbeans error reporting and program execution doesn't work properly, but if I delete the code Netbeans works properly again.

Is the following invalid Java syntax?

```
public class A
{
    public class InnerA
    {
    }
}
```

and

```
public class B
{
    public void transform(A a)
    {
        a.new InnerA()
            {
            };
    }
}
```

In my specific case, I have a running simulation, and `A` keeps track of all of its inner class instances and lets them all perform transformations on itself over the course of a period of time. So each inner class will exist for some number of seconds, doing its thing, then its owner will dispose of it.

Other classes are responsible for working on `A` by adding anonymous versions of the inner class which specify the action.

It works if I remove InnerA from A, making it its own class, but for my case it makes more sense to have it be an inner class of A.

In reality, my inner class has other properties and methods as well, but this is a simple example. The `a.addInner(a.new InnerA(){})` seems to break Netbeans as long as it is there. Should I file a Netbeans bug, or is this illegal syntax usage?

EDIT...
Since some people are very curious about how exactly Netbeans is breaking for me, here it is: sometimes the program will not execute via Netbeans run command, it instead says there are still errors in the code. The code file with code similar to that example has the file marked as having errors, but the code editor part does not show any errors in the code. If I make changes in the code (as simple as adding whitespace) and resaving, sometimes the file list in the tab of open files removes the error symbol from the file, sometimes not, and sometimes the list of files in the file explorer panel removes the error symbol, sometimes not (sometimes they are out of sync with each other in this manner), and if neither show an error then sometimes it will run, but when it does try to run Netbeans says that it cannot find the class, leading me to believe that it did not compile it even though it did not mark the file as with error.

Comment: what do you mean by "_seems to break Netbeans_"? Can you post the exact error message you get? Also, if it were an SSCCE, we could simply copy and paste it to our IDE and reproduce the error you get.

Comment: There isn't a method called `addInnerA` in class `A`. Are you trying to change the inner class of A?

Comment: @jlordo You are correct. I edited my choice of words.

Comment: @Jean Waghetti No, this is just an example, and it was supposed to be a very short and simple one. Whatever happens in addInnerA is irrelevant here, as the a.new InnerA() { } is what breaks it.

Comment: @Loduwijk we still don't know what "_seems to break Netbeans_" means. You have to post the **exact error message**...

Comment: It matters because in your example *you have not defined `A.addInnerA(InnerA)`*. It matters, very, very much. Additionally, *your call to `A.addInnerA` in `B.transform` is not syntactically correct*. Like I said in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17843007/45914), if you fix these two issues, then what you have is perfectly fine. That is, if you take what I have in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17843007/45914) and that causes an issue in NetBeans *then you have a bug*. But if you continue to ignore your syntax errors, we can't help you.

Comment: @jlordo, it is broken. Sometimes netbeans shows the file in the tab at the top to have an error, sometimes not, sometimes it shows the file in the explorer on the left to have an error, sometimes not, but it never shows an error in the code editing area, no red unnderline and no red tick mark in the scroll area on the right. Sometimes it runs, sometimes not, if it does, it says it cannot find the main class even though it exists and Netbeans has the main class set properly. It is broken.

Comment: @Jason, it is an _example_. What I had is not my actual code. My actual code is many thousands of lines distributed across dozens of files and many packages. Anyway, I fixed the typo you mentioned, edited in the ); though the addInnerA is still irrelevant since it doesn't actually even exist, as this is an example which is merely analogous to my code. But still, yes, for the sake of being complete, your exact example copy/pasted breaks. So yes, it must be a Netbeans bug, and I had assumed it was going to be, but I wanted to double-check. ...

Comment: cont ... Proclaiming "Here is a bug!" when Java spec doesn't do what I was trying to do would have looked stupid. So instead I double-checked to make sure I wasn't going to waste peoples time and space on a bug board with a bug that wasn't a bug. Which is why I put a simple example here. And if leaving stuff out is bad, then we should down-vote all the code examples which include an elipse in place of irrelevant code.

Comment: And before anyone else complains about anything which is irrelevant to the question, in case they do, I specifically stated that netbeans stopped reporting errors properly and the run command stopped working. So even if my actual code had been invalid, technically it would still be a bug in netbeans regardless. But a bug caused by incorrect code and a bug caused by correct code are different orders of magnitude in severity, the latter being severe. Regardless, the point of my question was (or so I thought) clear, and many of these comments are off topic. I was asking specifically aboout...

Comment: ... declaring an inner anonymous class within a class which was not the parent of the inner class. I was fairly certain it should be fine; I did not see why it would not be fine. But I thought I would ask. And if I have a few little nit-picky issues like typos or using a wrong term (which was edited out before the down-vote), I think I have the right to be human; I have already been working on this project for about 8 hours today, and I will still probably be working on it for another 5 to 7 hours more today at least, and when I'm not working on the code, I'm doing some other work for it...

Comment: ... And I am not even exaggerating either. I have probably worked on this project (code plus other stuff) for more than 100 hours last week alone, and I wrote many thousands of lines of code in many different packages of the project during that time alone, so sue me if I'm a bit exhausted and make a few little stupid mistakes. Again, I asked specifically about whether you can use an anonymouse inner class in an external class in that manner. If that was not clear enough, then make a suggestion about how it could be clearer!

Comment: I really applaud your efforts, but you are preaching to the choir here. Many regular answerers on SO program just as much as you. Calm down a little and think about what needs to be done to answer the question. You currently have one answer that compiles correctly. You've stated your code is more complicated than that, so you need to decide whether it is the complexity that is the problem or your example that has eliminated it. It's entirely possible that the example you gave is so simple, that the problem is gone. Having been in your position, it's probably the complexity that is the problem.

Comment: NetBeans **is** using `javac` if you turn off the "compile on save" feature. That compiles in a different way if I'm not mistaken. If that is turned on, turn it off and see if that changes anything.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thank you for that. If I turn off compile on save, the odd problems go away. So it works with compile on save turned off. If I turn "compile on save" back on again, it once again breaks. Annoying, and I'd rather have the feature on, but that will work for now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not valid because `A` doesn't have an `addInnerA` method defined (as you've shown). Did you mean to include one here and we should give you the benefit of the doubt on that?

Also, you're missing a `);` on the end of the eleventh line of `B`. Should we give you the benefit of the doubt on that one too?

If so, that is you actually did define `addInnerA` in your `A` class and you meant to also include a closing `);` for the call to `addInnerA` in `B.transform`, then what you have is valid syntax and that would be a genuine bug.

But let's be clear here **what you have shown us in your post is not valid syntax**. It's only valid if you defined `A.addInnerA(InnerA)` and fix the call to `A.addInnerA` in `B.transform`.

In fact, with

```
public class A {
     public class InnerA {
          public void action() { }
     }

     public void addInnerA(InnerA innerA) { }
}

public class B {
     public void transform(A a) {
          a.addInnerA(a.new InnerA() {
              public void action() { }
          });
     }
}
```

I can successfully get this to compile with Oracle `javac`.

Comment: I don't think the syntax will be valid: `a.addInnerA(a.new InnerA() ...`

Comment: It's perfectly valid. I can get exactly what I've shown here to compile.

Comment: No, I don't have an addInnerA in my code nor do I have a ); in that spot, as that is just an example. My class which is analogous to A is more than 500 lines of code, and the one analogous to B is more than 400. Rather than strip out extra stuff, I typed up a bare bones example. addInnerA is to be assumed, but addInnerA itself is irrelevant to this issue as I was asking about the anonymous inner class defined in B. Anyway, thank you for the answer. Not sure why I didn't compile on the command line - possibly because my brain is getting fried by this huge project and working 80+ hours per week.

Comment: Look. When you post an example, the smallest example that actually reproduces your error, you need to get it right. If you come here and you post with syntax errors, we're going to focus on them. But I gave you the benefit of the doubt and *removed* the syntax errors. And then in that case I can assure that what you have is legal syntax. If you take *my* example, and put that in NetBeans, does it give you the error? If so, you found a bug. If not, it's not actually an example the reproduces the error. Do you get the point now?

Comment: I do, but I never asked for help fixing a compile-error; the code caused error reporting to stop working. The question was "Can you define an anonymous inner class within a class other than the inner class' parent in this following manner." In lots of questions you probably have to look at what you're mentioning; "My code won't compile" questions. But on topic here, it didn't matter if I omitted braces, omitted semicolons, and did other odd things. The question is preserved, and any such issues are like typos: they are irrelevant to the specific question. Besides, I fixed the typo long ago.

Comment: You are *still* not getting it. I gave you the benefit of the doubt, removed your syntax errors, and told you what you have is legal. Read my answer again, I implore you. You don't seem to get that. You *also* don't seem to get that it matters very much if you're code has omitted braces, semicolons etc. because it *distracts* from your genuine question. I repeat: I gave you the benefit of the doubt on these issues, and told you that what you have is legal. Had you never had those syntax issues, others would have focused on your underlying question too. It matters, a lot.

Comment: I am getting it. Your answer technically contained within in it the answer to my question, and I thanked you for that, and I will probably accept it as the accepted answer if I don't write up a detailed answer-summary of everything that we found out, which I probably won't since I detailed most of it in my question-edits. But your answer was hidden behind some fluff about other things which would have made better comments to the question and partially obscured your point. Also, people keep focusing on those other things and down-voting, despite having a valid question which provides all ...

Comment: ... necessary information required, and despite me keeping on top of it with updates. In this situation, having a -4 downvote total is an abuse of the system. It's a good question well maintained which provides meaningful and useful information to anyone with the same problem, so it should be at at least +1. Of course I'll be defensive against such immature behavior. But whatever, I have bigger fish to fry. Again, thank you for confirming that Java accepts what I asked about.